# Simple PHP function and variable confusion

Tags: php

I have a couple of simple PHP functions I am using. One to detect wether the user is on an iPhone, and one to resize images if they are.

```
<?php 

/* User agent function */
function userAgent(){
    $browser = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    if ($browser == true)  { $var = 1; }
    return $var;
}

/* Image resize function */
function imageResize($width, $height) { 

    $var = userAgent($var);

    if($var == 1){
        $width = round($width / 2); 
        $height = round($height / 2); 
    }else{
        $width = round($width);
        $height = round($height);
    }

    echo "width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\""; 
} 

?>
```

The problem is, if I manually change the $var to 0 or 1 in the userAgent() function, the images do not resize, but if I change the $var to == 0 in the imageResize() function, they do.

Why is the variable not carrying across from the first, to the second function, or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strpos` never returns `true`. You will need to test for `$browser != false`, otherwise your function will never recognize an iPhone.

However, your code is unnecessarily complicated, and returning an integer is not really useful here. I would recommend a  simplified rewrite:

```
// Make it return `true` or `false` instead of `1`, also make it universal
function isAgent($string)
 {
    return (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$string) !== false);
 }


/* Image resize function */
function imageResize($width, $height) { 

    if(isAgent("iPhone")){
        $width = round($width / 2); 
        $height = round($height / 2); 
    }else{
        $width = round($width);
        $height = round($height);
    }
    // Consider using CSS
    echo "style=\"width: {$width}px; height: {$height}px;\""; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, really hand to know that, although it feels very strange using a double negative. I am not using CSS because I am resizing images, and its better to use inline HTML for that.

I am also going to list multiple user agents so in my original question, I will just change $browser = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone"); to $browser = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"$array");

Really useful stuff though, thanks again.

Comment: @dani you're welcome. Just note that `strpos` doesn't accept arrays, you'll have to build a loop to check multiple user agents. Using CSS or inline HTML should not make a difference in any case, it's just that CSS is the more "modern" way of doing it...

Comment: you are correct, my bad. I don't think it makes much difference, although inline CSS seems pointless only in this example, just because of HTML's native support of the width and height properties. Interesting topic of conversation actually, because I am not sure what they benefits of either are.

Comment: @danixd The trend is to use CSS properties for this because the size info can then be separated into a style sheet (where it really belongs, rather than in the markup) but seeing as it's inline either way, it doesn't really matter here. I think it's a good thing to use CSS anyway, though, just as a matter of principle.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are only returning `$var` if the user agent is iPhone, otherwise you are trying to return an undefined variable (within your userAgent function)

try:

```
function userAgent(){
    $browser = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $var = 0;

    if ($browser !== false)  { $var = 1; }
    return $var;
 }
```

Comment: Perfect, taking me a while to get used to this PHP malarky :) Thanks!

Comment: My bad Pekka, altered so it checks for boolean false instead of true.

Comment: Oh yes @Pekka is correct. The ($browser == true) part doesn't work. It seems so unintuitive that you have to say if $browser isn't false...

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect the `$var` argument to be processed by the `userAgent` function?  In that case, you need to specify it as an argument.

```
function userAgent( $var ) {
...
```

Otherwise, you may want to initialize the `$var` in the function body.  It's a wise strategy to keep your `if-then-else`s symmetrical:

```
if( $browse ) {
   $var = 1;
} else {
   $var = 0;
}
```

And you can write this a bit more succinct like

```
function userAgent() {
   $browser = .....
   return $browser ? 1 : 0;
}
```